# CultureInfo.NumberFormat Hide Comma

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, number-formatting

I am trying to create a NumberFormat that will not use Groups at all.

I would like all numbers to be displayed with NO commas.

Example:

- 1999 instead of 1,999
- 2000000 instead of 2,000,000
- etc...

Unfortunately, I am using a 3rd Party control that is a NumericEditor and it applies a CultureInfo setting on it to show commas. So I need to create a `CultureInfo` instance that doesn't use Grouping at all.

I have tried this:

```
int[] groupSize = {0};
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes = groupSize;
```

Also...

```
 CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
 culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = String.Empty; // Throws and exception with the 3rd party control
```

The closest I have gotten is...

```
 CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
 culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
```

I don't like this solution at all because instead of a comma its white space and it definitely looks odd.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not posting the stack trace of the exception was a bad idea.

Comment: @Ben f. why don't you put your comment in an answer form and I will accept it for it is the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider implementing [custom formatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx).

You can assign your custom format provider like this:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat = new MyCustomFormatter();
```

That might work if they (3rd party control developers) didn't implement some "magic".

Comment: Its sealed now at least.

Answer (score 1):

What 3rd-Party control are you using and have you tried reflecting (using something like .NET Reflector) to see how they are using the CultureInfo class, because in regular old C# code, setting the NumberFormat.NumberGroupSize = new int[]{0}; works as well as NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeperator = String.Empty;. It seems the 3rd Party control might be using the CultureInfo properties in a non-standard way.